# How to fix an "Could not find 'store'" error in React-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-thunk

I'm trying to add React-Router to my application, but getting an error:
[image: Error image]

[Here is a code](https://0bin.net/paste/zGUREqeG4cZPfonq#udg+j2-uQGYBnknwcuHXeRdxicdVELQmwNwhEAkzRbi)

Comment: Did you import your store in the main file? Doesn't look like you did in that link.

Comment: Hmm... That's really helped me. Thank's!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to import store to the main file